# .net object explorer control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, user-controls

Does anyone know of an object explorer control for .net winforms (or webforms)?
By "object explorer" I mean something like the visual studio object explorer that I can use it in my own program.

I found these links on the net:
1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/oe.aspx - It is pretty old and I don't know if relevant today.
2. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-embed-vs-nets-object-explorer-program-t1342274.html - nobody answers him..

Comment: How does said *object explorer* behave compared to a `TreeView`, two `SplitPanel` controls, a `ComboBox`, and a custom menu strip? Or is there a more specific part you are looking for? It would also help if you explained what you are wanting to do. I think I understand the resource on the first link ...interesting. The 2nd link is useless.

Comment: @IAbstract: I need a user control that allows me inspect objects and I don't really care how exactly the ui will be. I need the same functionality like the vs object explorer. This is for testing purpose - some tool in addition to unit tests.

Comment: Then I would recommend looking into the code project resource, then. It may be a fairly easy project to quickly get updated.

Comment: Can you elaborate by adding the purpose of the explorer? Do you have control over the input objects? If the audience is technical then you may want to consider directly embedding som form of REPL (http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

Comment: @smaclell: I want to build a tool that allow me load dll, specify class and it will display all the class's methods. Then I can execute each method and explore the return value. I just want to see the output of my methods using that object explorer control.

Comment: So basically list types, then list methods then allow for the methods to be instantiated (potentially with parameter values)? I think a REPL type window would be ideal or potentially a simple form + some reflection. It would definitely get alot more dicy in the details and I would highly recommend seeing if there  is a simpler way you can provide the same user experience due to the details. Either way I definitely do now know of such a control but good luck trying to find a solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the PropertyGrid? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code in order to build an object tree:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/reflection/article.php/c5885

Answer (score 1):

The one that Visual Studio uses is available in WinForms. It's called PropertyGrid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

You can add all sorts of Attributes to your code so that it displays how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a reflector. Did you check [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)? It's an open source assembly browser. You can get the code and customize it as you wish.

Comment: Read the question - I need user control which I can integrate in a tool I develop.

Comment: I know, but you can check the source code of ILSpy and see how this kind of thing can be done. I don't know exactly what are the requirements for the tool you are building, but maybe extending ILSpy would be easier. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy to code this one yourself using routines in the System.Reflection namespace. It's just enumerate all types in assembly & enumerate all methods, properties, variables in type.

Comment: You right - I wrote one. The problem is that it not act as I need. For example, in case of IEnuerable that created from entity framework result - I cannot see the query result.